# get checksum of a directory in golang

Tags: go, tar

Is there a way to generate a checksum of an entire directory and its contents in golang?

I know how that one can tar the directory and then grab the checksum of that, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to avoid? There's not really much difference between taking the checksum of the tar stream, and recursively reading each file and directory listing. I mean the tar format is technically not needed, but you need _some_ directory format to checksum, so tar might be as good as any.

Comment: I think it's necessary to know the reason and context for this checksum. A checksum of a directory is not an easily defined thing, since a directory isn't a "thing", but rather a high-level concept, used by humans. In particular, do you need the checksum to be valid across different filesystems and/or operating systems? Should modification and access times, permissions, or other metadata be taken into consideration? Without knowing your use case, it's impossible to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: I see, my reasoning was mostly that the top level directory is quite large. I have decided to take a different approach specific to my overall problem, but thanks for enlightening me on the lack of difference between the two.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [Parallel digestion](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) example from the https://blog.golang.org/pipelines, starting from the **Digesting a tree** section, probably can give you some ideas.

So you can go from:

```
// MD5All reads all the files in the file tree rooted at root and returns a map
// from file path to the MD5 sum of the file's contents.  If the directory walk
// fails or any read operation fails, MD5All returns an error.
func MD5All(root string) (map[string][md5.Size]byte, error) {
    m := make(map[string][md5.Size]byte)
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !info.Mode().IsRegular() {
            return nil
        }
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        m[path] = md5.Sum(data)
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return m, nil
}
```

To the parallel version: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines/parallel.go

Answer (score 0):

For `go mod` Russ Cox wrote [dirhash](https://github.com/golang/mod/blob/ce943fd02449f621243c9ea6e64098e84752b92b/sumdb/dirhash/hash.go).

There's two approaches, one hashes the files in a directory, the other hashes a zip while ignoring non-deterministic information like file date.

Extra metadata isn't necessarily meaningful for file contents and should probably be ignored.  I recommend investigating the zip method first if it is suitable for your needs.